# Server to Client communication Client unable to receive messages from server

Tags: java, socket.io, client-server, serversocket

[image: Both are the pictures of the output]I am working on a POC where Server will send multiple messages to the Client and Client should receive the message and should print the message.
But the server sends the message properly but client unable to receive.

I have already tried with the for loop for 10 iterations the while will terminate and then the client receives messages from server.

Here both are the classes:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

public static void main(String gg[]){

try{

Socket socket  = new Socket("localhost",8080);

System.out.println("Client Started...");

InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 int x;

while(true){

x = isr.read();

if(x=='\n'){
break;

}

sb.append((char)x);

System.out.println("Readable Message: "+sb);
}

}catch(Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();

}

}


}

    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Server {

    public static void main(String gg[]){

    try{

    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);

    Socket socket = ss.accept();

    System.out.println("Server Started...");

    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);

    String message = "Hello";
    int i=1;
    while(true){
    osw.write(message+i);
    osw.flush();
    System.out.println("Server written.:"+message+i);
    Thread.sleep(200);
    i++;
    }    
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }

    }
```

Here is the error message from the client once I stopped server.

```
C:\harsh\java\book2>java Client
Client Started...
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
        at Client.main(Client.java:23)
```

The iteration on the server went upto 100 when I stopped server.

As it is a part of POC according to that the server will never stop and will  always sends messages might be some delay is possible but will send the message from the loop.

I except it to receive all the messages sent from the server side.

I m adding another sets of images after I tried it with flush in the server I want output to of a single string not in pyramid type.For say first iteration it is sending "Hello1".So it should receive "Hello1" not that pyramid.[image: This is the image after adding flush method after write in Server.]

Comment: Try calling `OutputStreamWriter#flush` after you call `OutputStreamWriter#write` in your server. You'll also need to write a newline character, `'\n'`, if you want the client to stop reading.

Comment: Great it worked receive messages but in weird format. I ll update the question with the image.Please look.

What I want is for say 1st iteration "Hello1" is the message.
So it should print "Hello1" only. but it is printing pyramid here

Comment: @JacobG. I have updated the question with the image please check it once more

Comment: Because you're reading one character at a time in the `while` loop, only print `sb` after the loop has terminated. And like I said, you need to also send a newline character, `'\n'`, if you want your code to stop after `"Hello1"`.

Comment: @JacobG. I placed print statement outside the while loop and it is not again printing the message.

Comment: Then you're not sending the newline character that terminates the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194131/discussion-between-harsh-kumrawat-and-jacob-g).